# DIfference between `less mount` and `mount | less`

Tags: bash, mount, less

I was trying to look at the output of the `mount` command. `less mount` gave the following error:

```
(base) jafar_isbarov@jafar-IdeaPad-3-15ADA05:~$ less mount
mount: No such file or directory
```

When I ran `mount | less`, however, it worked fine.

Why does this difference exist?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, if it makes any difference.

Comment: On the other hand: Why do you think these *should* do the same thing? What's the purpose of `|`?

Comment: It is a pipe symbol, so it provides output of the `mount` operator as input to `less` operator. Isn't this also what `less mount` does?

Comment: `less xyz` treats "xyz" as a file, not a program to run and read input from. Check your `less` man page.

Comment: I'd recommend to start all over; read the Bash guides at www.tldp.org

Comment: Will do. Thanks. @Hannu

Answer (score 1):

`less mount` runs `less` on a file called `mount`, and then fails with the error you've attached since there is no such file.

`mount | less` runs the executable called `mount` found in your `$PATH` (e.g., on my system, running `which mount` will find it in `/bin/mount`), and then pipes the output of that command into `less`.

Comment: @tom-yan - missed the pipe there, which was kind of the whole point of this answer. Thanks for noticing and for the fix!